# Is "judges excellent X" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

Is the construction *We judge excellent the work done by the contractors* correct, or should one write instead *We judge the work done by the contractors [to be] excellent*?

I suppose that the same construction applies to verbs with similar meaning, such as *regard* or *consider*. Or are there differences?

Comment: "Regarded" would require "as" ("We regarded as excellent").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the latter form, "We judge the work done by the contractors to be excellent." The preference is to put the verb as close as possible, within reason, to the object of the action. In this case, we're *judging* the *work*, which favors the latter construct.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is this only a preference, or is the first form outright wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is *wrong* on its face, but it does make for a very awkward construct.